# wait for 3 seconds or user click

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a situation where I am waiting for a small period of time say 3 seconds and move on. But if the user clicks my on-screen button then move on as I would have anyway. Both events will trigger the same behaviour namely to update text on the screen. Any thoughts??

New to Android but mclovin' it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private Thread thread;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutxml);

    final MyActivity myActivity = this;   

    thread=  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(3000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
            }

            // TODO              
        }
    };

    thread.start();        
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        synchronized(thread){
            thread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It waits 3 seconds to continue but if the user touches the screen the thread is notified and it stops waiting.

Comment: Sorry, mSpashThread was actually thread, forgot to update that reference making the code as general as posible

Answer (score -3):

Try the following,

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Runnable clickButton = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // whatever you would like to implement when or after clicking button
            }
        };
        button.postDelayed(clickButton, 3000); //Delay for 3 seconds to show the result
}
```

Comment: please don't post the same answer to several questions - they either don't fit exactly or the question is a duplicate and should be flagged as such