# Android - wait for touch event

Tags: android, touch-event

In my Android app, I'd like to display several images on the screen in sequence, waiting for a touch event (a single tap) to go to the next one.  I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791307/wait-for-3-seconds-or-user-click) that one way to do this should be:

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity {
    private Thread thread; //defined inside the activity

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_image);

        [get an image and create a bitmap from it]

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        wait(100000000); //large number
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex) {                    
                }         
            }
        };
        thread.start();    
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            synchronized (thread) {
                thread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, this code appears to just skip the waiting and immediately jump to the last image.  What's wrong with it, and/or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, event listeners in Android are for waiting - you don't have to provide any delay.

Simply set the `onTouchEvent(...)` listener on the ImageView and show the first bitmap. When the ImageView is touched, show the next bitmap and so on. All you have to do is keep a count of how many touches there have been in order to know which image to show (image 1, 2, 3, 4 etc).

Example...

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity {

    int imageNumber = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_image);

        //get an image and create a bitmap from it

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            imageNumber++;
            switch (imageNumber) {
                case 2:
                    // show image 2
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // show image 3
                    break;
                ...
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, works perfectly!  Since my images are coming from OpenCV processing and won't all be available at the start, I added a private boolean flag readyToDisplay to the class.  After all manipulations are complete, I set it to true.  Then, your code becomes: `if (readyToDisplay && evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {`.